# How to fix sound?

Tags: java, android, audio, service, timer

I have been stuck on this for way too long now. In my main menu screen, I have a mute button. I want it to call a method in my background service, which mutes all of the MediaPlayer audio that would be played in the background of my game.

Here I am calling mute from my Main_Menu (x starts as 0):

```
   if ((x%2) == 0) { //If it's even
            TwentySeconds.unMute();
            Toast.makeText(Main_Menu.this, "UNMUTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        x++;
    } else { //If its odd
        TwentySeconds.myMute();
        Toast.makeText(Main_Menu.this, "MUTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        x++;
    }
```

Here are the methods in the service which actually do the muting:

```
       public static void myMute() {
        ten.setVolume(0, 0);
        three.setVolume(0, 0);
}
public static void unMute() {
        ten.setVolume(1, 1);
        three.setVolume(1, 1);
}
```

Here are the actual media players, which play at intervals:

```
static MediaPlayer ten;
static MediaPlayer three;
```

The problem is, I am getting a null pointer exception here:

```
TwentySeconds.myMute();
```

**and**
    ten.setVolume(0, 0);

By the way, manager is instantiated like so:

```
AudioManager manager;
```

and later on:

```
manager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

**Here is something that might be causing the issue:**

I am getting the error whenever the audio plays (which plays fine):

```
QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
```

I would really appreciate any feedback (positive or negative)!
Let me know if you need any more code.

Answer (score 0):

You must start your service first

In the method in Main_Menu

```
Intent svIntent = new Intent(this, TwentySeconds.class);
startService(svIntent);
```

And then you call `TwentySeconds.myMute();`

Remember add service to manifest file:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".TwentySeconds" />
```

Comment: Twenty seconds is the class name and ten is the mediaPlayer inside that class. How should I initialize these two in a separate class? Thanks for your response!

Comment: How can I know TwentySeconds is your class name, you don't provide fully your code, man :)

Comment: gist.github.com/anonymous/8596f908272acb266d62

Comment: @Rich check the updated answer, please thumb up if it is useful

Comment: Wait, do you want me to put TwentySeconds.myMute(); after startService(serviceIntent)? I can't do that because I want to mute it when the button is pressed. Public void mute is actually the onClick method for my mute button, so I need to mute it from there.

Comment: I will make sure to mark you as best answer (+ 15 rep) **and** like your answer (+5 rep) once I get this to work!

Comment: I replaced this in the manifest: <service android:name=".TwentySeconds" />

Comment: where is android:enabled="true"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94382/discussion-between-rich-and-dauruy).

Comment: sorry, my proxy doesn't allow me to join chat. But you initialize `ten` and `three` in onStartCommand, so your service have to run to init your `ten` and `three`. About the onClick method for myMute button, just do it normally. I have tried your code, and it worked. Open the app and music will play, when I click setting menu, music stop (I put Twentyseconds.myMute() in setting menu click handler).